# Firebase security rules for hierarchical structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**How can I give users access to data for anything below a certain node in a hierarchical structure AND make it easy to query? Can this be done in Firebase, or do I have to abandon my beloved Firebase and go back to...grumble grumble...RDBMS?**

I've tried two different ways. One makes it easy to query but hard to restrict access. The other makes it easier to restrict access but means I have to do nested loops to aggregate all my data.

Specifically, I have a typical business organization:

- Company

  - West Region

    - Division 1

      - Department 1
      - Department 2
    - Division 2

      - Department 3
      - Department 4
  - South Region

    - Division 3

      - Department 5
      - Department 6
- Company 2
  ...etc.

At the lowest (department) level, I have orders whose amounts I have to aggregate.

## First Attempt

### Data (Denormalized)

```
{
    "Orders": {
        "UniqueID1": {
            "company": "Company",
            "region": "West Region",
            "division": "Division 1",
            "department": "Department 1",
            "amount": 19.8
        },
        "UniqueID2": {
            "company": "Company",
            "region": "West Region",
            "division": "Division 1",
            "department": "Department 1",
            "amount": 20.1
        },
        ...and so on.
    },
    "Users": {
        "Bob's UID": {
            "departments": {
                "Department 1": true, // Note that these two departments combined are Division 1
                "Department 2": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Rules

```
{
    "Orders": {
        ".indexOn": ["company", "region", "division", "department"],
        ".read":false,
        ".write":false,
        "$order_id": {
            ".read": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('departments').hasChild(data.child('department').val())"
        }
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

#### Pros

- Querying is flexible, e.g: `ordersRef.orderByChild('division').equalTo('Division 1')`.
- Querying is fast. This works in under 2 seconds for 200k records.

#### Cons

- I don't believe I can restrict access with kind of a structure. I get `permission_denied` based on the rule I have above. I think it's because I've run into the issue of "rules are not filters, tsk tsk tsk".

## Second Attempt

### Data (More Normalized)

```
{
    "Orders": {
        "Department 1": {
            "UniqueID1": {
                "company": "Company",
                "region": "West Region",
                "division": "Division 1",
                "amount": 19.8
            },
            "UniqueID2": {
                "company": "Company",
                "region": "West Region",
                "division": "Division 1",
                "amount": 20.1
            },
        },
        "Department 2": {...
        ...and so on.
    },
    "Users": {
        "Bob's UID": {
            "departments": {
                "Department 1": true, // Note that these two departments combined are Division 1
                "Department 2": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Rules

```
{
    "Orders": {
        ".read":false,
        ".write":false,
        "$order_id": {
            ".read": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('departments').hasChild(data.child('department').val())"
        }
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

#### Pros

- I can restrict access using security rules now by reading one department at a time.

#### Cons

- I don't think I can do a deep AND variate index on "Orders/$order_id/" +company, region, or division, which means I have to make a separate call for each department's orders to aggregate at some higher level.

Comment: From your first attempt rules: ...`.child('department').hasChild(data.child('departments')`... do you have `department` and `departments` switched up? According to your data, I think that would be the problem.

Comment: @qxz it was a typo in my question and actually is correct in the database. I'll edit the question. Great catch, though!

Comment: Huh, I wonder why that rule doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first data structure looks reasonable. You can access specific orders you have access to, and you already can find the list of the divisions for a specific user.

To also allow accessing the order for (for example) a division, you'll need to add a secondary index that maps a division to a list of order IDs:

```
{
    "Orders": {
        "UniqueID1": {
            "company": "Company",
            "region": "West Region",
            "division": "Division 1",
            "department": "Department 1",
            "amount": 19.8
        },
        "UniqueID2": {
            "company": "Company",
            "region": "West Region",
            "division": "Division 1",
            "department": "Department 1",
            "amount": 20.1
        },
        ...and so on.
    },
    "Users": {
        "Bob's UID": {
            "departments": {
                "Department 1": true, // Note that these two departments combined are Division 1
                "Department 2": true
            }
        }
    },
    "OrdersByDivision": {
        "Division 1": {
            "UniqueID1": true,
            "UniqueID2": true
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can find the list of orders for a division with a direction lookup under `OrdersByDivision` and then loop to load the orders:

```
ref.child('OrdersByDivision/Division 1').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    ref.child('Orders').child(snapshot.key).once('value', function(order) {
        console.log(order.val());
    });
});
```

Most developers that have done web development without Firebase are afraid this pattern will be slow. But given that Firebase retrieves the items over an already established connection, this is actually quite fast. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)

Comment: Thank you, Frank! I'll incorporate the secondary index. It's not something that intuitively came to me coming from a relational DB background! If I needed to pull orders at a regional level, would it make sense to have another index of DivisionsByRegion and then query OrdersByDivision?